# Android set background color to TextView in styles.xml

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

In my application, I want to set a style to the `TextView` which will make the `TextView` look like a header as shown in the following figure-

[image: "General" is the heading in this image.]

When I apply the style from the `styles.xml` (given below), it applies the font and font color as specified. But, it does not apply the white background. Can we  at all do this?

The style defined is like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="settings_header">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom"> 10dip </item>
    <item name="android:background"> @color/white </item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft"> 10dip </item>
    <item name="android:layout_width"> match_parent </item>
    <item name="android:layout_height"> wrap_content </item>
    <item name="android:textSize"> 22sp </item>
    <item name="android:textColor"> @color/black </item>
    <item name="android:textStyle"> bold </item>
</style>
```

The code which applies the style is like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textview.setTextAppearance(ScrSettings.this,R.style.settings_header);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use white text color over white background? :)

Comment: The color is just an example. Color can be any color. But the thing is a colored background and some text over it. Anyways, edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, this works

```
textview.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.settings_header);
textview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

The question is still not answered fully as, setting the background to the `TextView` twice is not what we want. We had already set the background in `styles.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

**public void setTextAppearance (Context context, int resid)**

Sets the **text color**, **size**, **style**, **hint color**, and **highlight color** from the specified **TextAppearance** resource.

This is the actual output of **setTextAppearance**. **Why you are thinking about background color without reading the behaviour of** setTextAppearance **method ?**.

If you want all properties you are setting in **styles.xml** use `style="@style/settings_header"` in XML file only.

I hope you understand this.

**EDIT**

To set background color at run-time use **setBackgroundColor** method.

Comment: Actually I want to decide the style of the `TextView` (Header or Subheader) at run time. I even tried `style="@style/settings_header` and it works fine. But I don't want it to be staic i.e. in xml and want to define it run time as shown in the code above. Is there any other way to set the background color at run time?

Comment: Unfortunately, even `setBackgroundColor()` is not working. But `setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)` is working. But setting background resource from xml also should work. Anyways, posting this as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajkiran setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) <- it works! and setBackgroundColor(R.color.something) doesn't work, of course!

Answer (score -2):

if you not have a color folder in your res then you need to replace @color/white with #ffffff

Comment: I have defined colors.xml in which I have a white color with the same value. I even tried putting `#ffffff` instead of `@color/white` but still I could see no background.

Answer (score -3):

i dont now if its help

try this 
 @color/#fff

instead of "white"

good luck

Comment: @color/#fff isn't an appropriate value. It won't even compile. And even `@color/#ffffff` is errorneous; since when we say @color/[name] it implies we are calling an element named [name]. So this is not the answer of my question.